# Multiple video.js problems with chrome

Tags: video.js

I am having issues with using video.js and chrome.  On chrome 24 video does not seem to play.  Playback starts for a quick second and then just stops.  This even is true with the video on the video.js homepage. I have tried from multiple PC's.  On chrome 23 playback seems to be fine.  When playback stops I just see a video error event in the console.

However on the PC that has chrome 23 I am having an issue using the wordpress plugin.  Any page containing a link created by the plugin wont scroll.  This is true for single and multiple videos

In both cases IE and firefox(using flash since I only have an .mp4) seem to have no issues.

Has anybody seen anything like this?

Comment: A note on chrome 24.  Disabling the flag for hardware video decode made the video playback just fine.  Which is weird as I thought IE9 plus did hardware video decoding and they worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me with Chrome 24. I wouldn't rule out the video being the cause, instead of the player.

I've tried out tons of Html5 players lately and most of the problems were due to video encoding.

For instance, videos encoded with Miro Video Converter were not showing up on Firefox, stuff like that.

The only encoding software I've found with Html5 options which seem to universally work is Any Video Converter: http://www.any-video-converter.com/

The free version does everything I need it to.